# udk 4.7 commands as start up parameter

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculus, unreal-development-kit

I have a packaged UDK 4.7 app. I can set graphic settings in the command line  like:

**sg.ResolutionQuality 25**

Is there a way to set this settings via start up parameter like:

**app.exe -sg.ResolutionQuality=25**

(the example above does not work - is there an other syntax or does this not work at all?)

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are - by default - disabled in shipping builds.

The suggested (and simplest) way to manage that sort of needs is using INI files. The "sg" settings are in the INI file named `GameUserSettings.ini`, that you can find in (on Windows):

- on your project: in `.\Config\DefaultGameUserSettings.ini` (it will be packaged and used as defaults by your builds)
- on development builds: in `[YOUR-BUILD-DIR]\[YOUR-APP-NAME]\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor\GameUserSettings.ini`
- on shipping builds: in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\[YOUR-APP-NAME]\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor\GameUserSettings.ini`

In that file you can add and edit a section like:

```
[ScalabilityGroups]
sg.ResolutionQuality=25
sg.ViewDistanceQuality=0.1
sg.AntiAliasingQuality=0
sg.ShadowQuality=0
sg.PostProcessQuality=0
sg.TextureQuality=0
sg.EffectsQuality=0
```